# Why does my Updater only Update Java 64bit, not 32bit?

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, auto-update

I am using Win7 x64, and have both Java 7 64Bit and 32Bit installed. I recently examined my installed programs, and found that I was on update 45 for Java 7 64bit, but that the 32bit installation was stuck at update 11.

I then manually installed Java 32Bit u45, so that both are current.

But my question is: I have that obscure Java updater running, that appears from time to time asking if I want to update Java, which I always acknowledge. It seems to me that this updater only updates the 64Bit portion of Java, not the 32Bit installation.

Why? Is there any way to force the updater to update both versions?